# How check current media source link that is playing?

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

Is there a way to check current media source that is playing in VLC? What I mean is, I have a program that plays links to streams and it uses VLC to play them automatically so I was wondering if I can check the link that VLC is playing at that time?

Answer (score 0):

Once the video is streaming, click `Tools` > `Media Information`. The `Location` box at the bottom is the streaming url.

Comment: Okay, so if Location just says 'CON' then the software is blocking the URL from showing in VLC somehow, right? Is there some hidden log or another way that I can find it another way?

Comment: You can try tools > messages > set vebosity to (2) debug and it will give you a lot of info on the stream. You may find it in there.

Comment: not there either :(      avcodec debug: enabling direct rendering
avcodec warning: plane 0 not aligned
avcodec warning: disabling direct rendering
ts error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS duplicate (received 0, expected 1) for PID 0
ts error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS duplicate (received 0, expected 1) for PID 4095
ts warning: discontinuity received 0x2 instead of 0x5 (pid=256)